# C++ template partial specialization to do sizeof or dynamic size calculation of each argument

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I want to be able get the size of each argument

```
class MyClass(int a, char b, std::string c)
{
  ...
}

auto x = CreateInstanceAndCalculateSize<MyClass>(1, 'c', std::string("somthing"));
```

```
std::unique_ptr<T> CreateInstanceAndCalculateSize(Types&& ... Args)
{
    size_t size = either sizeof(Arg) or Arg.length(); // I think this requires partial specialization for each possible type of arg you encounter
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Types>(Args)...));
}
```

Comment: You want to find the number of elements in the parameter pack? That would be `sizeof...(Args)`

Comment: what are you actually  using `size` for?

Comment: no, I want to calculate the size of each argument. I'm going to use it for logging and then based on size decide some algorithm on how/where to allocate it. sizeof...(Args) is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for sizeof for primitive types, but then do something for my datatypes.

Comment: How about `size_t sizes[] = { sizeof(Args)... };` That'll give you a C-style array of the sizes in order. Or do they need to be compile-time constants?

Comment: I need partial specialization ... that means for int -> 4 ... double -> 8, mydatatype -> callSomeFunctionForDeterminingSize(instanceOfMyDataType)

Comment: `class MyClass(int a, char b, std::string c)` isn't even valid C++.  Can we at least get something valid down to the core of the problem? I suspect what Cruz said is your best bet, bit it's really hard to say with fantasy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
template <typename T>
size_t MySizeOf(const T& t) { return sizeof(T); }

template <>
size_t MySizeOf<std::string>(const std::string& s) { return s.size(); }

template <typename... Types>
size_t CalculateSize(Types&& ... Args)
{
  return ... + MySizeOf(Args);
}
```